# valgrind: invalid read size and stack overflow

Tags: c, stack-overflow, valgrind

Hello when I run this program for calculating the gcd through valgrind (this is the portion that is causing errors):

```
int gcd( int a, int b ) {

if( a == 0 || b == 0 )
  return a + b;
if( a < b )
  return gcd(b - a, a);
else
  return gcd(a - b, b);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int a = atoi( argv[1] );
int b = atoi( argv[2] );

int q = gcd(a, b);

fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", q);

return 0;
}
```

With **no arguments** I get

```
==22833== Invalid read of size 1
==22833==    at 0x3685636EB2: ____strtol_l_internal (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
```

and when I run it using **two negative numbers** ex: 'gcd -5 -4' I get

```
==516== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0x7fe601ff8
```

I believe the second errors (with the negative number inputs) is **because of the a < b part** is this true?
What part in the code is causing error 1 on its own?

Comment: What do you mean with no arguments? If you didnt pass any numbers in, a and b would be undefined, so you would get undefined errors.

Comment: If you have an error when you run with no arguments, you need to show the argument parsing code - the part that reads `argv`.

Comment: Yes for second error. `a < b` always,  which leads to stack overflow.

Comment: Show the  `main()` of the program

Comment: Yeah, theres your problem. You're calling atoi() on an undefined variable.

Comment: @SantoshA Thanks, edited to include.

Comment: @EyeOfTheHawks is this for the negative inputs one?

Comment: You should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No arguments**
You are calling atoi() on an undefined variable.
First, you should check

```
if(argc != 3){ //check if there are three arguments
    //error code
}
```

**Stack overflow**
with `a=-5` and `b=4`, `a < b` always.  This causes an infinite recursion, and eventually a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

When one of the inputs to `gcd` is a negative number and other one is a positive number, the recursion never ends. The positive number keeps growing and the negative number remains unchanged in each successive recursive call. Obviously, this causes stack overflow.

When you pass two negative numbers to `gcd`, the next recursive call gets you in that state too.